Window Trim Help!
I bought a house a few years ago after more than barely a walk thru.
Water pouring down my windows and walls from upstairs and downstairs.
Mold, the works.
Turns out the trim on the whole house is particle board.
Pulling the trim today.
No Z flashing, tape.....nothing.
I can see why it leaked.
What's my next move?


particle board?  That would be very unusual  How do you know it's particle board?  Perhaps you've mistaken Oriented Strand Board (OSB) for a kind of particle board.  Don't be too surprised to discover your entire house is made of OSB from the roof decking under the shingles to the floor itself (under the laminate/tile/carpet) unless your floor is a concrete slab. If you have joists under the floor and the house is recent - the 'web' of your floor joists is probably OSB as well.

There is a potential source of water in your picture.  That gutter looks like it might be touching the house siding.  The discoloration is higher on that side as well.

https://imgur.com/a/bHUHfKo

https://imgur.com/a/Zsq9lmX

Both west facing windows, upstairs and downstairs are completely rot. Behind the drywall in both bedrooms were pouring water through the trim. Mold in both rooms.

The gutter isn't touching the wall. Is capped, and has "not sure what it's called" curved flashing .

Do you thing I should apply flashing tape, z flashing and then Hardi-trim??

Flipping flippers!
